# Syntax error on python 2 which I can't understand why

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Hi I was trying to shut down raspberry pi via arduino and made a python daemon that shutdowns the raspberry pi.

When I first write code and run it, it perfectly works but when I save it and run the code one more time, it doesn't run because of syntax error.

Here is my python code. 
    import serial
    import os

```
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)

while 1 :
   line = ser.readline()
   if line == 'shutdown\r\n':
      os.system("sudo shutdown -h now")
```

I'm trying to make it work whenever I need it. But this code only runs successfuly one first time, and when I give it a second chance it doesn't work and shows that the code has syntax error.

python version is 2

Comment: Didn't you ask this question yesterday? I remember people asking for the error that was shown

Comment: Please don't put an image of your code -- post _actual_ code.

Comment: Previous post has been removed, it seems. Still the same question, though: Please post the syntax error you get, including which line it's on

Answer (score 5):

Remove the `>>>` from your script